# Sending keyboard commands to Ubuntu through Python. Remote for my Blackberry

Tags: application-development, php, development, xdotool

I am trying to build a remote control application to control media on my Ubuntu. Does anyone know a way in order to accomplish this. The media keys in particular.

Thank you.

### **EDIT 1:**

I have tried using ***XTE***, but is seems python in truncating the input or there is a limit or something which means that you can't do Ctrl + Key key presses, which wont suit my needs.

I also tried ***uinput***, but alas you need to run it as root, which also will not quite my needs.

Now I am looking at [EVDEV](http://packages.python.org/evdev/) which seems promicing, that is if I can get it working.

Comment: I understand that this is a very incomplete hint but try looking at http://code.google.com/p/autokey/ . It's open source and in python and it does in part wht I believe you're looking for. Their code might be of help.

Comment: Thank you I will definately check it out as I used to use AutoHotKey for Battlefield 2. Appreaciate it, seems to be an issue finding things for unix o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the latest version please check out Pymote. This remote layout has changed, and I still need to update the image on the page.

This version has been simplified quite allot and requires only Python and Xdotools to be installed.

[Pymote on GitHub](https://github.com/drpain/pymote)

Answer (score 1):

### **EDIT 2:**

I though I would share this, should someone look for something similar and happen upon this.

The easiest way I found to send the keystrokes through Python is by installing ***xdotool*** which is a unix based scripting tool, wich is pretty awesome. It supports all the multimedia keys. Including the context menu a.k.a "Menu".

***So what did I need it for?***
I built a remote for my ubuntu since my Compro Remote stopped working.

***How does it work?***
It leverages Apache, Bootstrap, PHP, Redis, Python and finally xdotools (Boy that's a mouthfull). I created a mini website which I access through my WIFI with remote buttons which when clicked sends the command in the background to the PHP  Script running on Apache.

This PHP script then saves the command and values in Redis which is polled constantly by Python. Once Python picks the command up. It checks it in the dictionary of commands and sends the appropiate command line to xdotool. Xdotool then runs the Media Keys or starts Rhythmbox or XBMC or pauses and plays. Whatever. So far it's working like a charm.

---

### Head on over to Github

**I am putting a github repositry together for this. I hope this helps someone, somewhere**

Installation instructions etc. to follow in said Github page.

[Web The Black Mote Github Page](https://github.com/drpain/web-the-black-mote)